# How to get the results of a query to the values passed in in an array (mySQL and PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a page where the user can choose which overdue invoices to download via a ZIP file. I am changing an existing query to only pull out those invoices that have been checked by the user, where the job id numbers are sent in to the PHP function via an array.

The existing query that downloads all the invoices is:

```
$sql = '
select i.jobid 
  from invoice i 
  join job j 
    on j.id = i.jobid 
 where i.total > 0
 ';

$Q = $this->read_db->query($sql, array($days));
```

$days is the number of days for which invoices are shown.

I have changed it to:

```
$ids = implode(',', $invids);  // $invids is the array sent in of invoice numbers
$sql = 'select `i`.`jobid` from `invoice` `i` WHERE `i`.`jobid` IN ' . $ids . ' join `job` `j` on `j`.`id` = `i`.`jobid` where `i`.`total` > 0 ';

$Q = $this->read_db->query($sql, array($days));
```

When I try and echo $Q->result(), I get an error `Call to a member function result() on boolean`. I am fairly new to mySQL, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: You cannot have two WHERE clauses in the same (level of) query. I suggest you see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is very strangely formatted and invalid, this is why it returned a boolean (false).

```
SELECT i.jobid FROM `invoice` i JOIN `job` j ON j.id = i.jobid WHERE i.total > 0
```

```
SELECT i.jobid FROM `invoice` i JOIN `job` j ON j.id = i.jobid WHERE i.total > 0 AND i.jobid IN('.$ids.')
```

Additionally, please always use PDO or Prepared MySQLI.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thank you, but the second one is returning the boolean error. The first query (which is the one someone else wrote that I am modifying) works fine. It's only when I add the `WHERE` part.

Comment: I added the second one too. You can only have one where clause in a query.

Comment: Please select my answer as the one that helped you so it may help others. I'm glad it works now :)

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: I solely posted the SQL to help him. But he is right, @Riva Portman; you should always use PDO for your database connections and queries.